# Ext js 4 controlling listeners from the controller

Tags: extjs4

I am new to Ext Js 4. My question is fairly simply but I just cant find it any documents or  any forums. I have a xtype: 'panel' that has an image map with several links on it. I am trying to add a listeners on that panel so that I can control it in my "controller". How can I accomplish this so that I follow the MVC model??

```
 {
    xtype:'panel',
    id:'tab2',
    html:
    '<div><img src="app/image/tableRoomPoster.jpg"  usemap=#conferenceRoom >'+
    '<map id="conferenceRoom" name="conferenceRoom">' + 
         '<div id ="remote"> <area shape="rect" alt="Remote" title="" coords="727,568,834,613" href="#" ></div>'+   
         '<div id ="virOfficeMain"><area shape="circle" alt="virOfficeMain" title="" coords="28,624,18" href="#" ></div>'+
     '</map></div>' +    

    '<div  id="toggleRemote" style="display:none"><img src="app/image/remoteShrink.png"  usemap=#controlRemote >'+
    '<map id="controlRemote" name="controlRemote">'+
            '<area id ="remoteOff" shape="circle" alt="Off" title="" coords="118,51,11" href="#" />'+   
                '<div class="playVideoMonitor" id="button1"style="display:none">'+
            '<area  shape="rect" alt="button1" title="" coords="20,74,42,87" href="#"/>'+
                '<iframe border:"block" width="302" height="174"src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/VHySPMCNS34" '+
                'frameborder="0" ></iframe></div>'+
            '<div class="playVideoMonitor" id="button2" style="display:none">'+
                '<area  shape="rect" alt="button2" title="" coords="61,75,85,89" href="#"/>'+
                '<iframe id="video2"width="302" height="174" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/ts8Q6LwDMcs" '+
                'frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></map></div>' 

     }],
     listeners : {
         afterrender : function(c) {
             c.getEl().on('click', function(e){ 
                 this.fireEvent('click', c); 
             }, c);
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use delegate option on your listener to listen for events emitting from an element embedded within your Panel.

Something like this:

```
listeners: {
    el:{  
      'click':{
          delegate:'img', 
          fn:function (event, target) {
               //do something
           }
       }
    }
 }
```

By the way this listener is on the panel directly and not in the controller - so it has no relation to your desire to use MVC. If you wanted to let controller take over in the `//do something` block then you can call `this.fireEvent('myEventName', somedata)` and then controller would listen to this event emitting from your panel and then it would do soemthing with the data.  - Now you got MVC :)